# Current selected row in a tableview side view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I am using a custom cell and table view within a Side View Controller.

The side VC uses one of the main available slide view controller styles, sliding in from the left to show a menu of navigation.

At the start the home view controller is loaded to the nav stack, with this side view controller.

How do I determine the selected row in this case? It is not as such a 'selected' row in the table, but the last chosen. So I am not sure the normal method would work.

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing, but I think I get the idea.

There are a couple things you could do.

Create a ivar, something like `lastSelectedIndexPath` and set that value in the `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath`method.

Add a method on each of your main view controllers query who it is(have each implement a common interface/protocol). Then have your side view controller call the method on the active main view controller and to ask "so... who are you?" This way you don't have to track what is displayed, you just query it when needed.

Comment: Sounds great, but I wouldn't know where to start. Are you able to provide any code examples?